# Proving that this sum $\sum\limits_{0 < k < \frac{2p}{3}} { p \choose k}$ is divisible by $p^{2}$

Tags: number-theory

How does one prove that for a prime $p \geq 5$ the sum :  $$\sum\limits_{0 < k < \frac{2p}{3}} { p \choose k}$$ is divisible by $p^{2}$.

Since each term of $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{0 < k < \frac{2p}{3}} { p \choose k}$ is divisible by $p$, only thing remains is to prove that the sum $$\sum\limits_{ 0 < k < \frac{2p}{3}} \frac{1}{p} { p \choose k}$$ is divisible by $p$.

How to evaluate this sum: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{p} { p \choose k} = \frac{(p-1)(p-2) \cdots (p-k+1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots k}$

Comment: This is identical to a problem that appeared on the Putnam exam a couple decades ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since we are working in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ we can write

$$\frac{(p-1)(p-2) \cdots (p-k+1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdots k}$$ as

$$\frac{(-1)(-2) \cdots (-(k-1))}{1 \cdot2 \cdots k}$$

= $$\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$

Let $N = [\frac{2p}{3}]$ and $M = [\frac{N}{2}]$

Thus what we need is

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$  $$  = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k} - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{M}\frac{1}{2k}$$  $$ =\sum_{k=M+1}^{N}\frac{1}{k}$$

Now $N+M+1 =p$ so we can rewrite as

$$\frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{M+1} + \frac{1}{N-1} + \frac{1}{M+2} + \cdots = $$

$$\frac{p}{N(M+1)} + \frac{p}{(N-1)(M+2)} + \cdots $$

which is $0$.

There are $N-M$ terms, which is even, so each term gets paired off.

Comment: Staggering proof! One question: What made you to think of an $N$ and $M$ like that.

Comment: 2p/3 is in the question you gave, and when you have alternating sums, it's natural to consider it as sum it all, and minus twice the negative terms.

Comment: @Chandru: Leaving the - signs wasn't going anywhere. Trying to get rid of them, you come up with the N and M. So yeah, what Soarer said. +1 to Soarer's comment.

Answer (score 3):

From your last equation one gets
$$\frac1p{p\choose k}\equiv(-1)^k\frac 1k\pmod p.$$
So the problem is equivalent to
$$\sum_{0 < k < 2p/3}(-1)^k\frac1k\equiv0\pmod{p}.$$

The case $p=1979$ was set as the first problem at the [1979 IMO](http://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx).
The method used for this extends to all primes, and no doubt
you can find solutions for the IMO problem out on the interweb.

Comment: Usually Problem 1 at the IMO was designed to be easier than the others (and in 1979 P1 and P4 had a maximum mark of 6 rather than 7) , but in 1979  [this problem had the poorest response](http://www.imo-official.org/year_statistics.aspx?year=1979) including from me.